# reduce method JavaScript, convert 2 objects in a single one

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have this array of objects:

```
const array = [{name: 'chips', size: 'medium'}, {name: 'burguer', size: 'large'}].
```

And I want to convert it to this:

```
{description: 'chips medium, burguer large'}
```

How can I do it? I have been trying with reduce without success.

Comment: Please read [ask] for tips on how to ask questions that are less likely to be closed and/or downvoted. Hint: add the code showing what you've tried.

Comment: It's possible with `reduce`, but that's the wrong tool. Can you show us how you'd do it with a normal loop?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve your desired result using a nested [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)s to first join each of the object values in the array and then the elements of the array into the final output:

```js
const array = [{name: 'chips', size: 'medium'}, {name: 'burguer', size: 'large'}]

const result = { description :
  array.map(obj => Object.values(obj).join(' ')).join(', ')
}

console.log(result)
```

Note it's possible the values in the object may not come out in the expected order (especially if you have modified the object) so it may be safer to refer to the properties directly:

```js
const array = [{name: 'chips', size: 'medium'}, {name: 'burguer', size: 'large'}]

const result = { description :
  array.map(({ name, size }) => `${name} ${size}`).join(', ')
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I'd think `\`${obj.name} ${obj.size}\`` would be preferred over `Object.values(obj).join(' ')`

Comment: @Bergi yes, that is probably safer. I've added a note to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [{name: 'chips', size: 'medium'}, {name: 'burguer', size: 'large'}];

const result = array.reduce((sum, cur) => {
    if (!sum.description) {
        sum.description = `${cur.name} ${cur.size}`;
        return sum;
    }
   sum.description += `, ${cur.name} ${cur.size}`;
    return sum;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array#reduce` method as follows but, as shown by @Nick using the `Array#map` method is more straightforward.

```js
const array = [{name: 'chips', size: 'medium'}, {name: 'burguer', size: 'large'}],

      output = array.reduce(
          ({description:d},{name,size}) => 
          ({description: (d ? `${d}, ` : "") + `${name} ${size}`}),
      {});
      
      console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented only using reduce method (not using maps) as below

```js
const array = [{ name: 'chips', size: 'medium' }, { name: 'burguer', size: 'large' }]

const result = {
    description: array.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
        Object.values(previousValue).concat(Object.values(currentValue).join(' ')), [],).toString()
}

console.log(result);
```

I think it is a good idea to go through "Sum of values in an object array" and "Flatten an array of arrays" in the mozilla documentation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: bear in mind that your output differs from what OP wants

Comment: you: `{
  "description": [
    "chips medium",
    "burguer large"
  ]
}`
OP: `{description: 'chips medium, burguer large'}`